# Merge together thousands of files in R -- in the right order

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to bind files together.  It is weather data for 50 years, each separated by year, and 75 replicates of every year. I want to bind the files together so that I have a continuous 50 year run.  I should end up with 75 50-year runs.

The files are named "clim" then rep ("01" through "99") then 01year ("2014" through "2064").  So clim01012014.txt is my first file.  But there are no reps that are multiples of 4.

My thoughts are to import my files as a list

```
files <- list.files("../Dropbox/APSIM/Climate files")
```

then use a function based on `rbind` to bind together files that have the same reps (that part in the middle, after "clim").

But I am having troubles conceptualizing how to tell R to bind files that have different endings, but the same middle numbers --

```
rbind(clim01012014.txt, clim01012015.txt, clim01012016.txt, clim01012017.txt, . . .)
```

Maybe I will need a loop instead of a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a loop for this and learning about `sprintf`.  This code binds my files together by the commonality of numbers in the middle of the filename and then writes the bound files out for use in another program.

```
data <-NULL 
for (i in 1:75){
  for (filename in l[[i]]){
  data <- rbind(data, read.table(sprintf("Bind/%s", filename)) )
  write.csv(file = sprintf("met%s.csv",names(l[i])), data, row.names = FALSE,     
  col.names=FALSE )
  } 
data <- NULL
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Input files:

```
set.seed(1)
files = sort(paste0('clim', formatC(sample(1:2, 10, T), width = 2, flag = 0), '01', sample(2014:2064, 10)))
files
# [1] "clim01012022" "clim01012024" "clim01012050" "clim01012058" "clim02012030" "clim02012032" "clim02012036" "clim02012046"
# [9] "clim02012047" "clim02012057"
```

Split by your "rep":

```
l = split(files, sub('clim(..).*', '\\1', files))
l
#$`01`
#[1] "clim01012022" "clim01012024" "clim01012050" "clim01012058"
#
#$`02`
#[1] "clim02012030" "clim02012032" "clim02012036" "clim02012046" "clim02012047" "clim02012057"
```

Now you can `lapply` over that list - smth like:

```
lapply(l, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, read.csv)))
```

Comment: This gets me a lot closer, but I don't understand if `l` is still a list?  From what I can tell, all my files are now ordered by rep, year.  When I apply the function, how is it different from applying to the list when it wasn't ordered?

Comment: @Nazer `l` is a list of vectors (each vector corresponding to your "rep"); for a given "rep" then, the internal `lapply` goes over each of the filenames, reads them and `do.call` later `rbind`s them together; the end result would be a list of `data.frame`'s, where each element of the list would have a given "rep"

Comment: Okay, good!  I am just getting an error right now (cannot open the connection), the fault is probably mine.  I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @Nazer try isolating the issue and then take it from there, e.g.: `lapply(l, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(y) {print(y); read.csv(y)})))`

Comment: this is my first experience with lists and I'm still struggling with it, even after some reading.  I'm trying to rewrite the final function, but I can't conceptualize what's going on.  Why `read`?  I changed to to `write.csv`, because I ultimately want all of these files written out, but then I just get an empty list.

Comment: @Nazer I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do at this point - my impression from OP was that you simply want to read some files into a particularly shaped list of data.frames, which is what this answer is designed to do (so I don't know where `write.csv` comes into play here); perhaps you want to write out the resulting list? In which case you'll need to `write.csv` the resulting list (from lapply), something like - `lapply(seq_along(result_list), function(i) write.csv(result_list[[i]], names(result_list)[i], ...`